# How to find the sum of first and last digit in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my program to allow the user to enter two lists of intergers, calculate the sum of first and last integers in each list and print the larger sum. At the moment it just outputs `list2` twice.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

n1 = [int(n) for n in input("List 1: ").split()]
list1.append(n1)
n2 = [int(n) for n in input("List 2: ").split()]
list2.append(n2)

s1 = 0
s2 = 0

s1 = list1[0] + list1[len(list1) - 1]
s2 = list2[0] + list2[len(list2) - 1]

if s1 > s2:
    print("Output: ", s1)
elif s1 < s2:
    print("Output: ", s2)
else:
    print("Output: Same")
```

This is what I get. I should be getting 12 as the Output.

```
List 1: 1 2 3 4 5
List 2: 5 6 7
Output:  [5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at what is actually in `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In addition to the answers to this post, I want to offer a tip. Python supports negative indexing, meaning, that if you want to get the last item of the list, you can write `list1[-1]` instead of `list1[len(list1)-1]`. Furthermore, if you want to get the second to last element, it would be `list1[-2]`, and so on!

Answer (score 1):

`append` adds an element to a list, rather than merging 2 lists, so `list1` and `list2` have the values: `[[1,2,3,4,5]]` and `[[5,6,7]]` respectively, just use:

```
list1 = [int(n) for n in input("List 1: ").split()]
list2 = [int(n) for n in input("List 2: ").split()]
```

Alternatively, you can replace your calls of `append` with `extend`, which will concatenate the lists provided together.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake:
`n1` is already a list, so your `list1` becomes `[[1,2,3,4,5]]` - it has 1 element which is list of 5 elements. Same as for `n2` and `list2`.

I rewrote your code, you can also use `lst[-1]` instead of `lst[len(lst)-1]`

```py
list1 = [int(n) for n in input("List 1: ").split()]
list2 = [int(n) for n in input("List 2: ").split()]

s1 = list1[0] + list1[-1]
s2 = list2[0] + list2[-1]

if s1 > s2:
    print("Output: ", s1)
elif s1 < s2:
    print("Output: ", s2)
else:
    print("Output: Same")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Take inputs from users
list1 = [int(n) for n in input("List 1: ").split()]
list2 = [int(n) for n in input("List 2: ").split()]

# SUM of first and last
sum1 = list1[0] + list1[-1]
sum2 = list2[0] + list2[-1]

# Checking
if sum1 > sum2:
    print("Output: ", sum1)
elif sum1 < sum2:
    print("Output: ", sum2)
else:
    print("Output: Same")

"""
OUTPUT:
-------------
List 1: 1 2 3
List 2: 4 5 6
Output:  10
"""
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the previous answers, and is actually worse in that it doesn't contain any explanation.

Comment: @tripleee I think you missed the comments

Comment: I don't think I did.

Comment: You comments are an explanation of what OP _already_ knew, as they implemented it in the first place, it's your _changes_ that should be explained